# Unable to mount an iPod Touch 3rd gen

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to manage the songs in my 3rd gen iPod Touch via gtkpod, or rythmbox. 
I’m currently unable to find out how to mount it, because it doesn’t show up in my list of devices. Am I missing something that’s right in front of me? 
From what I found via Google, the commands below should shed some light on the subject. However, I see no mention of new devices found, like "sda1", much less any mount points like "media/ipod", which would be super...

```
pi@pi3:~/share $ tail -f /var/log/messages
Mar 2 19:07:02 pi3 kernel: [877209.917331] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Mar 2 19:07:02 pi3 kernel: [877210.021877] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1299
Mar 2 19:07:02 pi3 kernel: [877210.021915] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 2 19:07:02 pi3 kernel: [877210.021929] usb 1-1.4: Product: iPod
Mar 2 19:07:02 pi3 kernel: [877210.021941] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Mar 2 19:07:02 pi3 kernel: [877210.021955] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: fc33064

pi@pi3:~/share $ dmesg | grep 
[877209.917331] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[877210.021877] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1299
[877210.021915] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

pi@pi3:~/share $ df -aTh
df: ‘/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc’: No such device
Filesystem Type Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root ext4 7.3G 4.5G 2.5G 65% /
devtmpfs devtmpfs 308M 0 308M 0% /dev
sysfs sysfs 0 0 0 - /sys
proc proc 0 0 0 - /proc
tmpfs tmpfs 313M 284K 312M 1% /dev/shm
devpts devpts 0 0 0 - /dev/pts
tmpfs tmpfs 313M 8.7M 304M 3% /run
tmpfs tmpfs 5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs tmpfs 313M 0 313M 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup cgroup 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls
mqueue mqueue 0 0 0 - /dev/mqueue
debugfs debugfs 0 0 0 - /sys/kernel/debug
configfs configfs 0 0 0 - /sys/kernel/config
fusectl fusectl 0 0 0 - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
/dev/mmcblk0p6 vfat 66M 21M 46M 31% /boot
tmpfs tmpfs 63M 12K 63M 1% /run/user/1000
gvfsd-fuse fuse.gvfsd-fuse 0 0 0 - /run/user/1000/gvfs
/dev/sda1 vfat 984M 414M 571M 43% /media/pi/RPI_USB
/dev/mmcblk0p9 ext4 4.1G 8.5M 3.9G 1% /media/pi/46b10c72-3ce5-41cc-a528-ef2942c96b53
/dev/mmcblk0p8 vfat 512M 129M 384M 26% /media/pi/B2E0-8069
/dev/mmcblk0p5 ext4 30M 6.2M 22M 23% /media/pi/SETTINGS
/dev/mmcblk0p16 ext4 5.6G 543M 4.8G 11% /media/pi/root-rbp2
/dev/mmcblk0p15 vfat 79M 21M 59M 26% /media/pi/boot-rbp2
/dev/mmcblk0p14 ext4 488M 2.3M 456M 1% /media/pi/data
/dev/mmcblk0p13 ext4 4.4G 1.7G 2.5G 41% /media/pi/f804d997-092e-47f5-ba62-71b004e8a177
/dev/mmcblk0p12 vfat 512M 205M 308M 40% /media/pi/C2CC-7190
/dev/mmcblk0p11 ext4 4.7G 961M 3.5G 22% /media/pi/root0
/dev/mmcblk0p10 vfat 66M 21M 46M 31% /media/pi/boot0
```

I’m guessing it’s not a matter of lack of current to power the ipod, because I am able to access the pictures in the iPod as soon as I connect it. File manager shows this:

```
gphoto2://[usb:001,007]/DCIM
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: After searching further for "new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg", it may be an issue with the current not being enough. lsusb shows 500mA as maximum power, and it might not be getting that much. I will check later.

Comment: `pi@pi3:~/share $ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/007 | grep -Ei '(iconfiguration|maxpower)'`

shows

`iconfiguration 5 PTP
MaxPower 500mA

iconfiguration 6 iPod USB Interface
MaxPower 500mA
iconfiguration 7 PTP + Apple Mobile Device
MaxPower 500mA`

Comment: I've changed to an iPad charger and the results is the same. It seems it's only being mounted as a PTP device. 
On PCManFM, it shows "iPod" (with the "unmount" icon), but this only leads me to the gphoto2://[usb:001,007]/DCIM folder. I don't see a way to get to the rest of the content.